# Gesture Gloves to Integrate Into Existing Software

Tags: home-electronics, wearable-technology

I'm working on coming up with suggestions for an alternate interface to an existing piece of software, and one avenue I wanted to explore was using gesture gloves. They don't need to be particularly advanced (this isn't Minority Report), just enough so that I could get a basic image of gestures to process and interpret as gestures. Whether the data is given as an image from a camera or as raw sensor data is irrelevant. I would prefer is there is an API to handle the gesture recognition, but that's not a hard requirement.

I've already looked a lot on my own and am not coming up with great results. Most I'm finding are either not available for retail sale, being Kickstarted (Gest), or are strictly for VR applications.

Apologies if this isn't the right community, but I didn't see any others that really fit the question.

Comment: It may help to specify an upper price limit if possible.

Comment: I don't have a hard budget defined yet. I'm mostly just exploring options.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you will find such gloves (***please***, post here if you do).

On the other hand (see what I did there?) [programmable wristbands](http://www.lilygo.cn/claprod_view.aspx?TypeId=21&Id=1282&FId=t28:21:28) go for about  $18, with BLE, but I am not sure if that would get you the accuracy that you want.

But, wait, that is based on the EPS32, which generally has an accelerometer and 6 axis motion sensor. If the LilyGo does to, there are other wristband options (such as the [M5Stack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082Y6YTY5)) and/or it would be easy to add one.

LilyGo:

[image]

M5Stack:
[image]

Note that the M5stack also has a Grove connector, allowing you to add 300+ sensors & controllers by plug & play, no soldering required.

I would be interested to hear what you think about this.

Also, while this is the correct site for this question, please be aware that we now have a [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) sister site, which might be of interest.

Comment: I appreciate the info, but we gave up on this avenue pretty quickly and I just implemented a touchscreen instead.

Comment: A pity that. I would have loved to find some gloves. Perhaps consider wristbands to augment? What about brainwaves? Thought control sounds cool. There are dev kits from $100